# Подключение к базе данных MS SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, intellij-idea

**Цель**: Правильно прописать путь в application.properties для возможности отправки данных в базу данных MS SQL.

Как выглядит сейчас(был сделан для MySQL):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.36:3306/TestApi?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
spring.datasource.username=pas
spring.datasource.password=pas
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**Вопрос**:
Как правильно изменить url для подключения к базе данных MS SQL.

**Пытался**: Изменял строку на эту:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.120/dbo?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
```

Но эффекта не дало, также проблема заключается в том, что моя схема находится в папке, а их несколько и с разными схемами, которые имеют такое же название, как и у моей нужной схемы.

**БД** имеет название: dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё заработало.

Добавляем в `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://ВАШ ХОСТ;databaseName=dev;
spring.datasource.username=NAME
spring.datasource.password=PASS
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Также необходимо добавить в `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>7.4.1.jre11</version>
```

Очень хороший [сайт](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java?view=sql-server-2017) и информации достаточно, советую почитать.